# Add namespace to WSDL definition

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, xslt, wsdl

I have a very BASIC WCF service with WSDL defition as follows:

```
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:tns="urn:MyService" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" 
xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/**addressing" 
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
name="MyService" targetNamespace="urn:MyService">
```

I want to add the namespace xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" to the definition but i don't know where and how.

How do i add that namespace ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just edit and add the string xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

An example:

```
<definitions 
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
   xmlns:tns="http://example.com/"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
   xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
   name="WebServiceName"
   targetNamespace="http://example.com/"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

Comment: OK but there is no WSDL file in the Visual Studio 2013/2015 WCF project :(

Comment: Maybe try the svcutil util, there some other answers to similar WSDL questions that recommend svcutil

Comment: buddy the problem is hat i can't see the wsdl at all